# set mouse position via web api action

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, pinvoke

I have a console application in which I move the mouse to a desired position using User32.dll methods import.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

public void MoveBy(int x, int y)
{
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.MOVE), x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

When I use the same method which works for me in the console application from a web api method nothing happens.
I tried to change the application pool to my user account which is the one associated with the UI but it didn't help.

Any suggestion how I can accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of UI are you expecting WebApi code to have?

Comment: the current logged on user. that is why I changed the application pool to run with this user.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through a website, or it might be better to phrase you can't mimic you're results from a console application for a client using a website.

The mouse is controlled by your operating system and neither the server nor the browser will be able to access that functionality on a client's computer.

Comment: do you have a suggestion how it can be done via a website? perhaps using the web api as a proxy to working console application?